# OpenCV VideoWriter does not write anything

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am working on a Deep Learning algorithm for videos.
Given a video footage I want to save my results on another video.
To do so, I am using OpenCV and Python on Windows.
OpenCV worked correctly for my video preprocessing to train my model. I need to save my results but the VideoWriter method gives me no output file.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
outVid = cv2.VideoWriter( 'outputfile.avi', fourcc, fps, tuple(shape.astype(np.int)), 1)
```

I process every frame and then I write this frame in the output file

```
outVid.write(np.uint8(RECONSTRUCT_IMG))
```

There is no issue returned by the console, but the output file is a 6 Ko video file, which cannot be read  obviously.

I tried several codec for the fourcc (*'DIVX' should be used on Widows according to [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)).

Anyone with a similar issue?

Comment: give your program access to opencv_ffmpeg*.dll during runtime, e.g. by placing it into the workung directory.

Comment: if that does not help, try different codecs lile MJPG to limit/narrow error sources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61747295/11922226

Answer (score 0):

check that you have rights to write in this directory. 
If it was created by a root user or superuser, you might not have access.

I just remove and create the dir again and it worked