# OpenCV VideoWriter Not Writing to Output.avi

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, python-3.7

I'm attempting to write a simple bit of code that takes a video, crops it, and writes to an output file.

## System Setup:

```
OS: Windows 10
Conda Environment Python Version: 3.7
OpenCV Version: 3.4.2
ffmpeg Version: 2.7.0
```

## File Input Specs:

```
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1)
Type: Video
Video resolution: 640x360
Frame rate: 5.056860
```

## Code failing to produce output (it creates the file but doesn't write to it):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('croptest1.mp4')

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F', 'M', 'P', '4')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,
                      (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4))))

# Verify input shape
width = cap.get(3)
height = cap.get(4)
fps = cap.get(5)
print(width, height, fps)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        # from top left =frame[y0:y1, x0:x1]
        cropped_frame = frame[20:360, 0:640]

        # write the clipped frames
        out.write(cropped_frame)

        # show the clipped video
        cv2.imshow('cropped_frame', cropped_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Variations to fourcc and out variables tried to get codec to work:

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('ditch_effort.avi', -1, 20.0, (640, 360))
```

[Based on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320976/python-opencv-videowrite-doesnt-write-video) I should be able to refer to [this fourcc reference list](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) to determine the appropriate fourcc compression code to use.  I have tried a bunch of variations, but cannot get the output file to be written.  When I run the code, the #verify input shape variables print the corresponding 640, 360 and correct Frame Rate.

Can any one tell me what my issue is...would be much appreciated.

Comment: If anyone has a similar issue and is writing black and white image, you need to specify that the image is not in colour: `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0,(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))), False)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason of error is the differences between the dimension of the `cropped_frame` (640,340) and the dimension declared in the `writer` (640,360).

So the writer should be:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,(640,340))
```

Comment: I have a question concerning the details. So my out variable must always have the corresponding dimensions such that Y=y1-y0 and X-x1-x0. Is this correct?  And lastly, why is the time off by a margin of a few seconds. I tried matching the fps (5.056859927954619) (the 20 I had above was an error), but the time is still off from the original by an added 7 seconds

Comment: Yes, the writer `out` must have the corresponding dimensions with the frame you write.

Comment: What do you mean by time off? The fps you set and the actual fps are different?

Comment: To your first answer. Awesome...thanks again very much.  To your second, I had a fps of 20 in my 'out' variable in the code above because I pulled it from the website, however, my actual input file has a fps of 5.056860 (as in my above File Input Specs). I tried matching the decimal place the cap.get method gives me (5.056859927954619) and I still get an added 7 seconds (11:02-->11:09) Any idea why?

Comment: I guess that `cv2.waitKey(1)` makes a delay of 1 ms every frame so your video is a little bit longer than the original. Also, I've never tried to set fps in that such decimal number.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the codec I used (FMP4), I will try some others now like (*'DIVX) now that you informed me on the problem of syncing the net value of the dimensions.  The `cv2.waitKey(1)` likely has no effect, as I tested with out that section of code.  Anyways, I really appreciate all the help.  Thanks very much for you time, patience and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code : it works for me:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2




output = 'example.avi'
video = 'output.mp4'
fps = 33
codec ='MJPG'


vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
time.sleep(2.0)
# initialize the FourCC, video writer, dimensions of the frame, and
# zeros array
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec)
writer = None
(h, w) = (None, None)
zeros = None

while True:

    ret, frame = vs.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=300)
    # check if the writer is None
    else:
        break
    if writer is None:

        (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, fps,
            (w * 2, h * 2), True)
        zeros = np.zeros((h, w), dtype="uint8")

    (B, G, R) = cv2.split(frame)
    R = cv2.merge([zeros, zeros, R])
    G = cv2.merge([zeros, G, zeros])
    B = cv2.merge([B, zeros, zeros])

    output = np.zeros((h * 2, w * 2, 3), dtype="uint8")
    output[0:h, 0:w] = frame
    output[0:h, w:w * 2] = R
    output[h:h * 2, w:w * 2] = G
    output[h:h * 2, 0:w] = B

    writer.write(output)

    (B, G, R) = cv2.split(frame)
    R = cv2.merge([zeros, zeros, R])
    G = cv2.merge([zeros, G, zeros])
    B = cv2.merge([B, zeros, zeros])

    output = np.zeros((h * 2, w * 2, 3), dtype="uint8")
    output[0:h, 0:w] = frame
    output[0:h, w:w * 2] = R
    output[h:h * 2, w:w * 2] = G
    output[h:h * 2, 0:w] = B

    writer.write(output)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

print("[INFO] cleaning up...")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.release()
writer.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with OpenCV C++ in Ubuntu ubuntu 18.04. I was processing a video (converting to grayscale and then generating a "paint" effect).

I solved the problem successfully doing the following steps:

1. Use the VideoWriter with the following line:

```
    VideoWriter videoWriter("effect.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('m','p','4','v'), 15.0, Size(ancho, alto), true);
```

2. Convert the image (in my case was in grayscale) to BGR (do the same in case that your image is in RGB color space):

```
    Mat finalImage;
    cvtColor(imgEffect,finalImage,COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    videoWriter.write(finalImage);
```

After the execution, the code generates the video without problems.

You can found my code in the following link:
[Example Code in C++](https://icedrive.net/0/9dKwIKLoiQ)